# Jsdoc for ExpressJs app without using typescript

Tags: express, jsdoc

I try to comment my ExpressJS function using JSCode but it does not work as expected.

```
/** @typedef { import('express').Request} Request */
/** @typedef { import('express').Response} Response */

/**
 * Description
 * @param {Request} request - test
 * @param {Response} response - test
 */
function myRouteFunction(request, response) {
  //request.
}
```

I have installed the package `@types/node` and `@types/express`.

When I type `request.` I'd like to have a suggestion of all ExpressJS function in the `request` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request` and `Response` clash with `fetch` types from lib.dom. You can **rename types**:

```
/** @typedef {import('express').Request} ExpressRequest */
/** @typedef {import('express').Response} ExpressResponse */

/**
 * @param {ExpressRequest} request - test
 * @param {ExpressResponse} response - test
 */
function myRouteFunction(request, response) {
  //request.
}
```

**or create tsconfig file** for your project

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [ "ES2022" ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types" ]
  },
  "include": [ "*.js" ]
}
```